# How to come up with some average for rating

Tags: python, math

I have a database table for comments.
Users add comments, and the comments can be voted down or up.

If voted up, the vote count up is +1
if voted down the vote count down is +1

To get the sum, what I do is (vote_count_up - vote_count_down).

What I want to do next is calculate the rating average of the comments.

0.0, 0.5, 1.0...highest rating being 10.0

I am not particularly sure how I can achieve this.

```
 commentslen = len(comments)
 positiveRating = 0
 negativeRating = 0
 average = 0.0

 for comment in comments:
     positiveRating += comment.num_vote_up
     negativeRating += comment.num_vote_down
 total = positiveRating - negativeRating

average = total / commentslen
```

How can I put all this together?

Comment: What if there are 5 comments and they are scored like this (+5, -3), (+90, -20), (+35, -40), (+105, -2), (0, -9), would you expect the "average" to be 32.2 or 161?

Comment: Thank you. I would have preferred the final calculation to be between 0.0 to 10.0. Won't that be possible with the above?

Comment: I can think of a method to get a final calculation between 0.0 to 10.0 if the average was positive, the fact that it can be negative makes it difficult

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the `for a post on 10` part.

Comment: @Brad I meant the final calculate double should be within the range 0.0 to 10.0

Comment: @LearnToday, the way that you're calculating up- and down-votes doesn't make this "negative" and "positive" rating make sense. if instead you only had one number, which was between 0 and 10 for each comment, and averaged that, it would make more sense. However, the way that you have it right now, someone could even up- and down-vote at the same time. What happens if you see that?

I don't think the issue here is the code, but the data model.

Comment: How can the votes be constrained to 0 to 10? What if a comment has 20 upvotes? or one downvote? How could those be normalized to a 0-10 range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that in the way you're suggesting, if you have 100 votes, a `10` rating would happen if everyone gives upvote and a `0.0` rating would happen if you don't receive any upvote. At the same time, if you receive 75 upvotes, the score should be `7.5`. So I believe this 0-10 score can be can be calculated by multiplying the ratio between upvotes and total votes by 10 like in the following code:

```py
total_votes = positiveRating + negativeRating
average = float(positiveRating)/total_votes*10
```

I suppose that `type(total_votes)` is a int, so you'll need to convert it to float or the value will be truncated.

Comment: I see, so instead of a percent (divided by 100) it's perten (divided by 10). And you're thinking that if there are no upvotes on a comment but 3 downvotes then that just results in a 0 score for purposes of averaging? I think that makes sense based on the description though the practicality of that approach seems questionable.

Comment: Yeah. That's exactly what I thought.

Comment: Thank you @samlima. I just wanted something for presentation purposes. This can do that.